# Change locale dynamically after plugin is applied

Tags: formvalidation-plugin

How can I change locale after the plugin has been applied?

Let say I have "en_US" locale assigned. Now I want to change it on runtime.

I tried to re-apply plugin to element:

```
$(element).formValidation({locale: 'es_ES',....});
```

But no effect. Any idea?

How can I refresh the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### EDIT: 2015-06-18

Before you follow the solution bellow (***step 1 & step 2 (option 3)***), make sure that you downloaded the `i18n` add-on from [here](http://formvalidation.io/addons/i18n/), this add-on will help you define messages in different languages.

Include it and then use it as following:

```
$(form).formValidation({
    framework: '...',
    icon: {
        // ...
    },
    addOns: {
        i18n: {}
    },
    fields: {
        // ...
    }
});
```

For more information, see http://formvalidation.io/addons/i18n/

This is how to solve your problem:

1. Include the language file `es_ES.(min.)js` after including `formvalidation.(min.)js`.
2. Set the locale:

   - *Option 1:* Use the locale option as you provided in your question.
   - *Option 2:* You can add the attribute `data-fv-locale="es_ES"` to your form.
   - *Option 3:* Use the `setLocale` method:

     ```
     $('#yourFormId').formValidation('setLocale', 'es_ES');
     ```

#### NOTES:

- the `setLocale` method is not documented, to see its usage see
  the example here http://formvalidation.io/addons/i18n/.
- Option 1 & 2 should be used before you initialize the plugin **and without using the `i18n` add-on**.
- Option 3 after initialization.

Comment: HI, I tried Option 3 but does not update the locale in runtime. So let say I have a certain form with en_US locale as default. Errors are shown in english when you first load the page. Then if I change the language via dropdown menu to 'es_ES', and trigger $('#yourFormId').formValidation('setLocale', 'es_ES'); 

Errors keep showing in English, not spanish. 

Any other idea? Thanks.

Comment: You should also include the language file `es_ES.(min.)js` (step 1), check the example in the link provided in my answer.

Comment: It is included:
`
    <script src="/vendor/formvalidation-master/dist/js/formValidation.js"></script>
    
<script src="/vendor/formvalidation-master/dist/js/framework/bootstrap.js"></script>
    
<script src="/vendor/formvalidation-master/dist/js/language/es_ES.js"></script>`

Comment: My friend, it works now. I was missing this: addOns: {
                    i18n: {}
                },

Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved your problem and You're welcome :)